# How to evaluate function in the grid?

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, vector, infinite-loop

I have a function `f[a_, b_]: = b^a + a b`. 
`a` takes values `{1,2,3,4}`, and `b` - `{10,11,12}`.

How is it better to calculate all values? Grid-type output.

Also, for every `b` I need to calculate values of function from all `a` and then take an average. As a result of such computing I would like to have 2 numbers for every `b`:

`{b1, 1/4 (f[a1,b1)+f[a2,b1)+f[a3,b1)+f[a4,b1)}` 
(basically {`b`, average `f` for all `a`})

What is the shortest way to do that? Can I do this without loops?

Comment: the first part of your question needs clarification. If you want all permutations of `a+b` from the two lists then `Outer[Plus, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {10, 11, 12}]` is somewhere to start but maybe best to show what output you want from first part of the question

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I have much more complicated function and `a` and `b` just parts. So, basically,it's not a sum of two values `a` and `b`.

Comment: given the two example lists you have provided what output do you seek? You need to explain what you mean by "all values"

Comment: Value of function in each point (for every `a` and `b`) with values of particular `a` and `b`. Grid-type output.

Comment: in that case i think my answer addresses your question

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Will it work if function is very complicated and after that I plug in `a` I do numeric  inverse Laplace transform for every `b`? can I still use `Outer` function?

Comment: Yes. But if you want help here you need to provide all relevant information not release it in tid bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4};
b = {10, 11, 12};
```

To get all the values:

```
vals = Outer[#2^#1 + #1*#2 &, a, b]
(* {{20, 22, 24}, {120, 143, 168}, {1030, 1364, 1764}, {10040, 14685, 20784}} *)
```

To get the averages:

```
vals = Outer[#2^#1 + #1*#2 &, a, b];
Transpose[{b, Mean[vals]}]
(* {{10, 5605/2}, {11, 8107/2}, {12, 5685}} *)
```

To see what is happening, evaluate

```
Clear[x, y, a, b, vals, f]
a = Array[x, 4]; b = Array[y, 3]
vals = Outer[f, a, b]
Transpose[{b, Mean[vals]}]
```

Comment: Will it work if function is very complicated and after that I plug in `a` I do numeric inverse Laplace transform for every `b`? can I still use `Outer` function?

Comment: @Maria.  I don't really understand your question. The inverse Laplace transform of *what*? of `a`? In any case, `Outer` requires the list of `a` and `b` to be pre-determined. If you can define a function `f[a_, b_] := ... ` that takes an element of `a` and an element of `b` and does something to it, no matter how complicated, this should work.

Answer (score 3):

For the second part:

```
{#, Mean@Thread[f[a, #]]} & /@ b

(* {{10, 5605/2}, {11, 8107/2}, {12, 5685}} *)
```

For the first part:

```
Outer[f, a, b]
```